# How can I ensure that the message that Azure Function receives is only once?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function (Java) that listens to messages in an Azure Servicebus queue.

If the Azure Function takes a long time to complete, the message will be put back on the queue, the message will be sent again to the Function, and the Azure Function will be retried.

What is the default retry interval for messages sent from Azure Service Bus?

How can I ensure that the message that Azure Function receives is only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do that in java exactly but when I need
that kind of operation I normally use the ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete and read and complete the message at the same time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues

Or another way is by implementing the NoRetry policy:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I solved it by extending wmaxAutoRenewDuration from the default value and setting it to the same time as the timeout time of Function.　https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: @TAHyouno Doesn't it just mean the message will end up in dead letters even though the function is still processing it?